# Get onldey date from DateTime

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

How I can get only Date?
Now I get 3/2/2016, 1:34:07 PM.
I want to get 3/2/2016;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var n = curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```